# How can I work around the limitation of multiple root elements in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hopefully someone here will be able to help me with this problem.

I have the following data:

```js
[
  {
    title: 'Header',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Paragraph',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Container',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Paragraph',
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I want to render this in a list of `<div>` like this:

```html
<div class="sortable-item" data-depth="1" data-index="0">Header</div> <!-- Parent -->
<div class="sortable-item" data-depth="2" data-index="0">Paragraph</div> <!-- Child-->
<div class="sortable-item" data-depth="1" data-index="1">Container</div> <!-- Parent -->
<div class="sortable-item" data-depth="2" data-index="0">Paragraph</div> <!-- Child-->
```

I have built a component that would be recursive, this is what I have so far:

```
<template>
  <template v-for="(item, index) in tree">
    <div
      class="sortable-item"
      :data-depth="getDepth()"
      :data-index="index"
      :key="getKey(index)"
    >
      {{ item.title }}
    </div>
    <Multi-Level-Sortable
      :tree="item.children"
      :parent-depth="getDepth()"
      :parent-index="index"
      :key="getKey(index + 0.5)"
    ></Multi-Level-Sortable>
  </template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MultiLevelSortable',
  props: {
    tree: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return [];
      },
    },
    parentDepth: {
      type: Number,
    },
    parentIndex: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getDepth() {
      return typeof this.parentDepth !== 'undefined' ? this.parentDepth + 1 : 1;
    },
    getKey(index) {
      return typeof this.parentIndex !== 'undefined' ? `${this.parentIndex}.${index}` : `${index}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see not only I have a `<template>` as the root element I also have a `v-for`, two "no no" for Vue.js. How can I solve this to render the list of elements like I pointed out above?

**Note:** I have tried [vue-fragment](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment) and I was able to achieve the structure I wanted, but then when I tried using [Sortable.js](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) it didn't work, as if it wouldn't recognise any of the `.sortable-item` elements.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why can't you just wrap the list of elements in a `<div>`? By the way, in Vue 3 this restriction is going away. Also, you can't have multiple template tags in a component AFAIK...

Comment: @AlexMA The reason I do not want to have them wrapped in `<div>` is because I want parents to be followed directly by children and so on. Let me check the link you suggested.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure the only way to do it until Vue 3 is with functional components. See linked answer.

Comment: https://codepen.io/AlgeoMA/pen/bGdmRdQ if you want to play around with it.

Comment: @AlexMA Thanks for putting together a quick test. I'll let you know if this helps with my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexMA I was able to solve my problem by using a functional component. Here is what it looks like:

```
import SortableItemContent from './SortableItemContent.vue';

export default {
  functional: true,
  props: {
    tree: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return [];
      },
    },
  },
  render(createElement, { props }) {
    const flat = [];

    function flatten(data, depth) {
      const depthRef = typeof depth !== 'undefined' ? depth + 1 : 0;

      data.forEach((item, index) => {
        const itemCopy = item;

        itemCopy.index = index;
        itemCopy.depth = depthRef;
        itemCopy.indentation = new Array(depthRef);

        flat.push(itemCopy);

        if (item.children.length) {
          flatten(item.children, depthRef);
        }
      });
    }

    flatten(props.tree);

    return flat.map((element) => createElement('div', {
      attrs: {
        'data-index': element.index,
        'data-depth': element.depth,
        class: 'sortable-item',
      },
    },
    [
      createElement(SortableItemContent, {
        props: {
          title: element.title,
          indentation: element.indentation,
        },
      }),
    ]));
  },
};
```

The `SortableItemContent` component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="item-content">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in indentation"
      :key="index"
      class="item-indentation"
    ></div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="item-icon"></div>
      <div class="item-title">{{ title }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SortableItemContent',
  props: {
    title: String,
    indentation: Array,
  },
};
</script>
```

Given the data I have posted on my question, it now renders the HTML elements like I wanted:

```html
<div data-index="0" data-depth="0" class="sortable-item">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="item-icon"></div>
      <div class="item-title">Header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-index="0" data-depth="1" class="sortable-item">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-indentation"></div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="item-icon"></div>
      <div class="item-title">Paragraph</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-index="1" data-depth="0" class="sortable-item">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="item-icon"></div>
      <div class="item-title">Container</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-index="0" data-depth="1" class="sortable-item">
  <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-indentation"></div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <div class="item-icon"></div>
      <div class="item-title">Paragraph</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you again @AlexMA for the tip on Functional Components.